# composition of derivatives of pure functions: `General::ivar: is not a valid variable`

Tags: functions

Hi The following program does not do what I hope it to do:

```
W = (Exp[r #]) &; Wp = (D[W[#], #]) &;
Wp[x]
Wp[0]
```

`General::ivar: 0 is not a valid variable`.

I've been using a "fixup"

```
Clear[Wp];
Wp[x_] := (D[W[y], y]) /. y -> x;
Wp[x]
Wp[0]
```

but there are surely better ways of .  Thanks

Comment: Try `Wp = (Evaluate[D[W[#], #]]) &`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
W = (Exp[r #]) &;
Wp = Derivative[1][W];
Wp[x]  (* r Exp[r x] *)
Wp[0]  (* r *)
(* but you can just use W' *)
W'[0]
```